# How to disable hover panel for mobile devices

Tags: css, display-template, boot-strap

I am using https://responsivesharepoint.codeplex.com/ for my sharepoint site. So I have bootstrap integrated to my SP Site.

Can anyone tell me what is the most elegant way of disabling hover panel for mobile devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how elegant it is but I just use a little css in a media query like this:

```
@media(max-width:800px){.ms-srch-hover-outerContainer{display:none !important;}}
```

If you're writing your own search result display templates you could add logic there for disabling the hover event.